# Create a button with function like power button in android

Tags: android, android-button

I have a problem. I want to create a button and when the screen is on and I click it, the screen will be locked and dim like power button. I've tried so many ways, but it seems they don't work :(
Help me please. 
See my code below:

```
public void click(View v) {
    if (mgr.isAdminActive(cn)) {
      mgr.lockNow();
    }
    else {
      Intent intent=
          new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
      intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, cn);
      intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                      getString(R.string.device_admin_explanation));
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you want only your activity screen to be locked or the phone to be locked?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
   KeyguardManager solution: keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

For locking the screen use this method on button click,

```
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

and for disabling the lock use,

```
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

This will just hide the lock screen and will display if any incoming call or any such event is happening, it will display that screen. It wont display the lock screen.

When running the application, to disable from going to the lock state, just use `setKeepScreenOn()` is set to true. or use the xml attribute `android:keepScreenOn="true"`

Another way to prevent the device to go to the sleep or lock mode when the application is running is set this api to true - `setKeepScreenOn()`

And of course we need to give `permission android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD` in Manifext.xml file